# Visio - tabs not showing

Tags: tabs, microsoft-visio

I can only see pages by using the Edit then drop down to go to the pages are still listed.

Answer (score 7):

Happened to me also. It was because the window within Visio was not maximized. I probably hit Alt-F7 and got into "cascade" mode. If you resize Visio, it will let you cover up the page tabs for some reason.

Under the menu (but above the ruler), you should see a little Visio icon at the left. Right-click and hit "maximize".  Ta-Da!

Answer (score 1):

I think what may have happened is that the scroll bar at the bottom of the screen has been dragged all the way to the left.  Try clicking on the far left of the scroll bar and dragging it back to the middle and the page control tabs should re-appear again.