# Visio missing tabs

Tags: gui, microsoft-visio

I am working on a Visio 2007 drawing and the page tabs have disappeared.  It seems to happen only when the document is emailed.  How I can fix this problem?

Comment: Is it also locked for editing?

Answer (score 0):

There's a related question on SuperUser that might be of help here: [Visio - tabs not showing](https://superuser.com/questions/142483/visio-tabs-not-showing)